# Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 11

Tags: java, gradle

I maintain an internal library, and I have upgraded the JDK with which it's built and published from 11 to 17. I also upgraded from Gradle 6.8.1 to 7.4.2 at the same time.

When trying to use the new version of the library in some existing projects, I get this error :

```
Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 11
```

It's quite self-explanatory, but I don't get it because in my library, I define this in my gradle.build file :

```
sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11
```

So I expect the jar that I build to be JDK 11 compatible.. but clearly, it's not.

what am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like that with latest Gradle versions, we need to use the `toolchain` (instead of `sourceCompatibility` / `targetCompatibility` ) to define the compatibility of the jar we produce.

It worked for me when using :

```
java {
  toolchain {
    languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)
  }
}
```